# mpi4py - Get processor number on 2 CPU server

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am using mpi4py on machines that have multiple physical CPUs - e.g. one board with two XEON processors. I can get use

```
from mpi4py import MPI 
com = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = com.Get_rank()
```

to get the rank of every individual process, and I can get the name of the node with

```
MPI.Get_processor_name()
```

But what I can't get is the information if a process is running on CPU 0 or 1. How do I get access to this information during runtime? I thought this might be managed with NUMA nodes, but the mpi4py documentation does not even contain the string "NUMA".

Background: My processes also use multithreading, but only across one physical CPU. So my program runs into situation where processes fight for threads on CPU 0, while CPU 1 is completely idle. MPI does not move processes over to the idle CPU in this situation (at least for me), so I want to make sure I am assigning multi-threaded workloads to processes that live on different CPUs.

Comment: The underlying MPI library does the pinning (if any) so you must ask it to do it and report it. For example, with Open MPI: `mpirun -np 2 --report-bindings --bind-to core ...`

Comment: Yes I can print this information on the console with --report-bindings, but how can I access it in the python code? I am not running on the same machine all the time, so I cannot hardcode it. I could run --report-bindings into 2> stderr.text, open that and parse it at runtime, but there should be a better way I hope.

Comment: Does `hwloc` have python bindings? That should give you all information you need.

Comment: Your question assumes MPI tasks are pinned. Anyway, if you do not trust what you ask MPI via your `mpirun` command line, on Linux, write your own version of `grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status`